# Select last 30 days rows from MARA using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, opensql, sap-erp

I'm trying to `select` rows for last date change = 30 days.

I tried `LAEDA = ( sy-datum -30 )` in `where` clause, but it always generated error.I connect to `sap Abap database`.

[image]

The message error:

> [EIS-Material [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opcPa.png)] Error: ERPConnect.ERPException: Error while
>   receiving function return values: SYSTEM_FAILURE An error has occurred
>   while parsing a dynamic entry.    at
>   ERPConnect.RFCAPI.ReceiveFunctionResults(UInt32 connectionHandle,
>   RFC_PARAMETER[] importing, RFC_PARAMETER[] changing, RFC_TABLE[]
>   tables, Encoding apiEncoding)    at
>   ERPConnect.RFCFunction.ReceiveFunctionArguments(RFC_TABLE[]&
>   apiTables)    at ERPConnect.RFCFunction.CallClassicAPI()    at
>   ERPConnect.RFCFunction.ExecuteRFC(Byte[] tid)    at
>   XtractKernel.Extractors.TableExtractor.GetPackage(RFCFunction& func)
>   at XtractKernel.Extractors.TableExtractor.Extract()    at
>   XtractKernel.Extractors.ExtractorBase`1.Extract(ProcessResultCallback
>   processResult)    at XtractIS.XtractSourceTable.PrimeOutput(Int32
>   outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers,
>   IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server, Sap hana etc?)

Comment: I use sap abap.

Comment: What is the error message? (Please add to the question.)

Comment: @Richard I added the error message.

Comment: So, your external query tool is **SQL Server Integration Services** (SSIS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are using a third party tool to extract data from an SAP system. According to the error message, the toole makes a Remote Function Call (RFC) and handing the SQL to the ABAP backend. Then your where condition must be valid ABAP/Open SQL syntax, regardless of the database behind.

Your call (simplified) would look like this in ABAP (with new @-syntax):

```
DATA(lf_dat) = sy-datum - 30.

SELECT matnr
FROM mara
WHERE laeda >= @lf_dat
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_matnr)
.
```

The problem is, that you are not allowed to make this calculation within the the statement, as far as I know, so you have to use a variable. But since your third party tool only allows you to write a where condition I see no way to handle this, except with a static date in the condition:

```
laeda >= '20190106' "YYYYMMDD
```

You can add the ABAP tag to your question to attract more specialists on this ABAP specific topic.

Comment: In ABAP it's possible to use the host expression `@( sy-datum - 30 )` but it's forbidden within a dynamic where clause, so very probably it won't work with `Xtract IS`. I give more details in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see in the [Xtract IS](https://help.theobald-software.com/en/xtract-is/) online help that there's a custom function module named `Z_THEO_READ_TABLE` installed at ABAP side, which executes the SQL sent by Xtract IS. The module is provided in 2 flavors, one being for ABAP >= 740 SP 5, so I guess it's a version for ABAP SQL Strict Mode.

So, I thought that maybe you could write this ABAP-like Where Clause by using a "host expression", which is valid in ABAP SQL Strict Mode :

```
 LAEDA = @( sy-datum - 30 )
```

Based on the error message you have, "An error has occurred while parsing a dynamic entry", I guess that this function module does something like `SELECT (dyn-columns) FROM (dyn-table) WHERE (dyn-condition)`, i.e. all elements are dynamically defined at run time.

Unfortunately, the "[ABAP documentation sql_cond - (cond_syntax)](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenwhere_logexp_dynamic.htm) says that "**Host expressions are not allowed in dynamic logical expressions**."

So long, impossible to make a where clause as you wish.

There are probably many ways to get around this limit (like creating a SAPquery or BAPI in SAP and calling it from Xtract IS, etc.) but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

In mySQL / MariaDB, this works:

```
select ...
from ...
where date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
```

but we need to know what database you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You may try it, if you use SQL database:

```
Select DATEADD(Month, -1, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify ABAP formula like that through SAP Open SQL.

Not to directly resolve your challenge (as you have product limitation), here is how dynamic filter is achieved through AecorSoft tool:

```
(DT_WSTR, 4)(DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE())) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 4)DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()),2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 4)DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()),2)
```

For complete use case, you can check the blog [SAP Table Delta Extract Made Easy through Dynamic Filters](http://www.aecorsoft.com/blog/2019/5/13/sap-table-delta-extract-made-easy-through-dynamic-filters)